# How to publish a link from ios app on a wall on vk using vk ios sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, vk

When I share a link to a website on vk.com wall it shows website's title and thumbnail. How to do it using vk ios sdk? I tried to share a link inside a message like

```
VKRequest *request = [[VKApi wall] post:@{@"wall_id":@"0", @"message":@"http://somelink"}];
[request executeWithResultBlock:^(VKResponse *response) {
            NSLog(@"OK");
        }];
} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failed");
}];
```

but it doesn't show a title and a thumbnail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link to a website should be an attachment

```
VKRequest *request = [[VKApi wall] post:@{VK_API_ATTACHMENTS : @"http://somelink", @"wall_id":@"0",}];
[request executeWithResultBlock:^(VKResponse *response) {
        NSLog(@"OK");
} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"failed");
}];
```